# Numpy: array > 5 yields "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"

Tags: python, numpy

I know that in numpy you can't simply do conditionals on arrays as it doesn't know how to treat them and that this error is a result of that, however in my case my code is a lot simpler. I have:

```
# H and _H are 3x3 arrays with hand-assigned values
# uv1 is 3x57600 array of coordinates, hand assigned in a loop
HH = np.dot(_H,np.linalg.inv(H))
new_uv = np.dot(HH,uv1)
du = uv1[0,:] * new_uv[2,:]
u = new_uv[0,:] - du
u_greater_5 = u > 5
```

And the last line gives me the "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" error. u is of shape (57600,) and I can open up the interactive prompt and the following works fine:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> a > 3
array([False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

But the code in the previous block doesn't. I've also tried

```
np.greater(u,5)
u[u>5] = 1
```

But they give the same error as well. Any ideas?

Also, I don't know if this is related, but bizarrely, trying to access u[0] gives me a 3-vector of the same 3 values (the first value in u) whereas it should be a scalar? Considering its shape is (57600,) ?

Edit: the traceback, as per request:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ros2vid.py", line 333, in <module>
    process_frames(bag)
  File "ros2vid.py", line 239, in process_frames
    u_greater_5 = u > 5
  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Here's how I generate uv1:

```
# frame is an image loaded from a ros bag
uv1 = []
im_r = frame.shape[0]
im_c = frame.shape[1]
for i in range(1, im_r):
    for j in range(im_c):
        uv1.append([j, i, 1])
uv1 = np.transpose(np.array(uv1))
```

and the values of H and _H are just numbers I hard code in by hand. Something like:

```
h11 = u0 * cosphi
h12 = -alph_u
h13 = alph_u + u0 * (-cosphi + cz * sinphi)
h21 = -alph_u * sinphi + v0 * cosphi
h22 = 0
h23 = alph_v * (sinphi + cz * cosphi) + v0 * (-cosphi + cz * sinphi)
h31 = cosphi
h32 = 0
h33 = -cosphi + cz * sinphi
H = np.array([[h11, h12, h13], [h21, h22, h23], [h31, h32, h33]])
```

All the values up there like u0, cosphi, cz, etc. are simply scalars. I've individually checked them, and _H is assigned similarly as well. I've checked the shapes of H and _H and verified them to be 3x3.

Weirdly, I just tried u == 5 and that doesn't give me an error, u > 5 does.

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback? .

Comment: There is nothing further in the traceback. This is within a function I call from main. I will update the post but it doesn't contain anything enlightening unfortunately.

Comment: Can you check `type(u)`?

Comment: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: What is `u.dtype`?

Comment: It simply returns `object`

Comment: @HalT OK, that's what I suspected. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that `u` is a one-dimensional array of *objects*, and the objects are themselves one-dimensional numpy arrays with length 3.  I can reproduce the behavior you report as follows.  First, create a one-dimensional array of objects (length 3), and fill it with numpy arrays:

```
In [26]: u = np.empty(3, dtype=object)

In [27]: u[:] = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6]), np.array([7, 8, 9])]
```

Check the type and attributes of `u`.  First, it is a numpy array with shape (3,).

```
In [28]: type(u)
Out[28]: numpy.ndarray

In [29]: u.shape
Out[29]: (3,)
```

The first element of `u` is an array with length 3:

```
In [30]: u[0]
Out[30]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

The `dtype` of `u` is `dtype('O')`, which is numpy's representation for the `object` data type. (If you *print* `u.dtype`, it will show `object`.)

```
In [31]: u.dtype
Out[31]: dtype('O')
```

Now try `u > 5`:

```
In [32]: u > 5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-7f680a2a9455> in <module>()
----> 1 u > 5

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

`u == 5` doesn't generate an error, but it does generate a warning, and returns the *scalar* False:

```
In [33]: u == 5
/Users/warren/miniconda3/bin/ipython:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  #!/bin/bash /Users/warren/miniconda3/bin/python.app
Out[33]: False
```

To figure out why `u` is an object array, you can work backwards, checking the `.shape` and `.dtype` attributes of the variables that you use to create `u`.

Comment: Indeed, the dtype of u is `object`, so somewhere in between I must mis-assign values into `u`. Surprising that it still works rather normally for certain operations, but doesn't work for boolean checks.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this without iterating through the array in a python loop? I'm going for efficiency.

Comment: Yes the object dtype imposes a barrier to many array operations.  Some like addition 'percolate' through, others don't.  I don't know of a general strategy for testing which is which.

Comment: @HalT  The simplest fix is to ensure that `u` is *not* an object array.  To do that, you'll have to figure how it ended up as an object array.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your code with random variables. But it works fine here:

```
import numpy as np
H = np.random.rand(3,3)*10
_H = np.random.rand(3,3)*10
uv1 = np.random.rand(3,57600)*10
HH = np.dot(_H,np.linalg.inv(H))
new_uv = np.dot(HH,uv1)
du = uv1[0,:] * new_uv[2,:]
u = new_uv[0,:] - du
u_greater_5 = u > 5
```

I don't know if it depends on the values of `H`, `_H` and `uv1`. Can you copy-paste my code and verify if you have problems with that code.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this works, as I suspected. What might be the cause of the issue then?

Comment: Also, can you post the output of u[0]? Does it return a single value or a 3-vector of the same value thrice?

Comment: `u.shape` gives me `(57600,)`

Comment: You should verify the values of your `H`, `_H` and `uv1` variables.

Comment: I updated the OP for insight into how I assign uv1. With your snippet, I get a scalar when I lookup u[0], but in my code I get a [scalar, scalar, scalar] when I lookup u[0] and they're all the same value.

Comment: I just saw your edit. You actually have a uv1 with size `57600X3`, you have to transpose. (or that's what I see at first glance, I can be wrong thogh)

Comment: I just tried u == 5 and that works with my code, but u > 5 doesn't.

Comment: Actually, that just returns `False` and not an element-wise answer

Comment: @HalT I just saw you question was answered completely. Nice you got it working. Good look with ROS my fellow robotician ;)